# Path not work with chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to use the script [InstaPy](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy) but when I execute the script I have this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x106814d90>> ignored
```

I have put the chromedriver in the path `/Users/myname/Downloads/chromedriver`

My code is like this:

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/myname/Downloads/chromedriver')

#if you don't provide arguments, the script will look for INSTA_USER and INSTA_PW in the environment

session = InstaPy(username='test', password='test')
session.login()

#Reduces the amount of time under sleep to a given percentage
#It might be useful to test the tool or to increase the time for slower connections (percentage > 100)
session.set_sleep_reduce(95)

#likes specified amount of posts for each hashtag in the array (the '#' is optional)
#in this case: 100 dog-posts and 100 cat-posts
session.like_by_tags(['#dog', 'cat'], amount=100)

session.end()
```

I run the script like this:

```
python test.py
```

Python 2.7.10
selenium==2.53.6

Can you help to resolve this error ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you make the driver executable? `chmod +x /Users/myname/Downloads/chromedriver`

Comment: yes, when I use the google code https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started that's work

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `that's work` ?

Comment: the code in the google documentation

Comment: Got it. add the output of `python -V` and `pip freeze | grep selenium`